# How to handle a double inequality where all 3 spots have unknowns

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given the problem $4x \lt 2x + 1 \le 3x + 2$ solve for x.

I'm not sure how to go about solving this problem. No matter how I subtract or add the x's or multiply/divide the coefficients I cannot isolate the x. Here is one approach I took:

subtract 3x
$$
x \lt -x + 1 \le  2
$$

add 1
$$
x - 1 < -x \le 1
$$

divide by -1

$$
1-x > x \ge -1
$$

Then if I add or subtract an x it will just end up on the 3rd side again. It seems like this would happen no matter what combination I tried. What am i missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two inequalities.  They are together at the moment, but treat them separately.

The first is $4x<2x+1$, which I am sure you can solve.

The second is $2x+1\le 3x+2$.

Comment: ah, i knew i was probably missing something simple. Thanks.